# Trouble calling second Activity

Tags: android

Hi all and thank you in advance for any answers.

The problem Im having is that my second activity called "Calander.class" is not being called from my main activity call "ShiftSelection". Im new to coding and android in general and am just trying to learn the basics but this problem has really stumped me.
I have added the Activity to the Manifest file and think Im calling the Intents correctly but when running the application onClick of my Button which should call the second activity doesn't do anything.

What am I doing wrong? Very sorry if this is a simple answer but I assure you that I have tried and failed for many many hours trying different things.

My code for the first activity and manifest file is below.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;

 public class ShiftSelection extends Activity{

    Button openButton;
    RadioGroup shiftSelection; 

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.shiftselection);    

    shiftSelection = new RadioGroup(this);

    RadioButton shiftPattern1 = new RadioButton(this); //shiftPattern1 = 4 shift 
    shiftPattern1.setText("4 shift");
    shiftPattern1.setChecked(true);
    shiftPattern1.setId(01);

    RadioButton shiftPattern2 = new RadioButton(this); //shiftPattern2 = 6     shift        
    shiftPattern2.setText("4 shift");
    shiftPattern2.setId(02);        

    shiftSelection.addView(shiftPattern1);
    shiftSelection.addView(shiftPattern2);        

    Button openButton = new Button(this);
    openButton.setText("open");
    openButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

          @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
              Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Calander.class);
              int genderID = shiftSelection.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

            switch(genderID){

            case 01:
             intent.putExtra("shiftPattern", "1");
             break;

            case 02:
             intent.putExtra("shiftPattern", "2");
             break;
             }
             startActivity(intent);
             }

          });

    }

}
```

And the Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.examples"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".ShiftSelection"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Calander">
        </activity>              
</application>
</manifest>
```

Thankyou for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting your button incorrectly.
By doing so you are assigning the onClick listener to a button that will never be visible.

Instead of doing

```
Button openButton = new Button(this);
```

you should be trying to find the button in your existing layout by doing

```
Button openButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.openButton);
```

Replace `R.id.openButton` with whichever id you assigned your button in your `R.layout.shiftselection` layout file

The way you are doing it now you are creating a new button and then never attaching it to a layout so it will never show

Comment: Hi dymmeh, Thanks alot for your time and answer it was spot on! I changed my code and its solved the problem, Im glad that it was a simple fix. I've accept your answer and marked the tick, not sure if there is anything else I should do to vote you up?

Answer (score 3):

In your intent, instead of `getApplicationContext()`, try to use this

```
Intent intent = new Intent (this, Calendar.class);
```

maybe this helps you

Comment: Hi, Thanks for taking a look at the problem I chose "dymmeh's" answer but thanks all the same.

Answer (score 0):

Another idea that may help: use the onClick attribute of your Button View. You can set this to the name of *any* method in the scope of your app, although it's most common to use a method in the Activity associated with the View. The method signature is

public void *methodname*(View v)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for taking a look at the problem I chose "dymmeh's" answer but thanks all the same.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ShiftSelection.this, Calander.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

i got three changes you need 2 in activity and 1 in manifest

---

replace this code in **ShiftSelection.java** Activity

```
Button openButton = new Button(this);
```

to

```
Button openButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

and change this line (same activity's onClick method)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Calander.class);
```

to

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ShiftSelection.this, Calander.class);
```

---

then your **shiftselection.xml** should having one button like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <Button android:id="@+id/button1" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Button Open"></Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

---

finally most important you need to make entries for both activities in **AndroidManifest.xml** file like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.examples"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">

        <activity android:name=".ShiftSelection"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Calander"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>                
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

---

let me know if still you have trouble to do this.

Comment: Hi RDC, Thanks alot for your effort and i'll take a look at my manifest file as your example is including the " intent-filter " again for the second activity where as mine is lacking that but as of the minute its working fine thanks to "dymmeh".

Comment: .... Just wondering but is there any reason why it would be working fine atm without those extra filters, are those extra filters good coding practice? I would vote you up but still a newbie sorry.

Comment: @user1442782.. no problem mate, before some days i was on your place :) , btw [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html) and [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html) links surely clear your doubts about Intents and Intent Filters.

Comment: Cheers, Just reading through those links now, thanks for your help.